# Draw continuous CGPath with parts of different line width

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I need to draw a continuous path, but e.g. one line of the path needs to be thicker than the regular path width. Is there a way to accomplish this with the default API or do I have to calculate the path joints myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to break up the path yourself. A single path can only be drawn with a single graphics state.